# Is there anything wrong with leaving toilet tank below waterline?

Tags: toilet

In troubleshooting a problem with recurring flushing (turned out to be a worn out flapper) I lowered the tank water level to about an inch below what the manufacturer marked as the waterline. Flushing seems to work fine - plenty of force, refills, fine and the flapper is fixed. I'd like to conserve water by leaving the water line where it is now, but will I be causing some kind of problem if I do?

Answer (score 2):

As a volume reducer, people have put two or three bricks in the tank to conserve on the quantity of water used per flush.

Being down by 1 inch of head on the water level isn't much to worry about.

As long as it flushes the contents either way, you're fine.

Comment: Someone used some drink bottles filled with water in mine, and attached them with rubber bands. Worked well enough until the one of the rubber bands broke while I was away and the bottle hung up the float preventing it from filling, and I got a frantic/confused text from my wife to the effect of "Eww! Someone left a strawberry milkshake in the back of our toilet and now the toilet is broken! Help!"

Comment: Heh, rubber bands have a way of doing that.